# How can I filter a packet after an iptables MASQUERADE?

Tags: linux, iptables, nftables, netfilter, ebpf

I am trying to build a multi-WAN router based on Debian Buster (kernel version 4.19). It has multiple 'LAN-side' network interfaces (e.g. *lan0*, *lan1*, ... *lan**M***), and also multiple 'WAN-side' interfaces (e.g. *wan0*, *wan1*, ... *wan**N***). I have each WAN-side interface configured to masquerade outgoing traffic, like so:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o wan0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o wan1 -j MASQUERADE
...
```

Now my problem is that I find (using 'tshark' packet capture) that *some* outgoing packets 'escape' the masquerade, and egress a WAN-side interface with a *source-IP* that is *different* from the IP of that WAN interface. I was able to catch and drop *some* of these packets with the rule

```
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
```

... but unfortunately not *all* such packets. (I even found packets that have the source-IP equal to that of *wan0* trying to egress through *wan1*.)

**My Question:** Is there a way I can inspect and drop packets *after* they have passed the MASQUERADE operation? I understand that the 'nat' table's POSTROUTING chain is the last thing I can do with 'iptables', but is there anything I can do with, for example, **nftables**, or **eBPF**?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to do this, and it involves *tc*.

Here is how we can configure interface `${ifc}` to drop, on egress, any packet that does not have `${ip}` in its *source address* field.

```
h_ip=$(ip_to_hex ${ip})

tc qdisc add dev ${ifc} root handle 1: htb
tc filter add dev ${ifc} parent 1: prio 1 protocol ip basic match 'not u32( u32 '${h_ip}' 0xFFFFFFFF at 12 )' action drop
```

Where:

```
function ip_to_hex {
        IFS='.'; read -ra AD <<< "$1"; unset IFS
        printf '0x%02x%02x%02x%02x' ${AD[0]} ${AD[1]} ${AD[2]} ${AD[3]}
}
```